# Value is not setting from bean to form and form to bean-Struts

Tags: struts2, struts

I am not able get value from form to bean in action class.
Here small piece of code :
in jsp,i have text box like show below:

```
<input type="text" name="objectID.Norder" id="objectID.Norder" />
```

In action class ,i have added one name and getter and setter method as shown below:

```
 private String Norder;
 public void setNOrder(String norder){
      this.Norder=norder;}
public String getNOrder(){
     return Norder;
}
```

This is small piece of code in action class.Value of Norder is null when i submit form with valid inputs and early it was working fine .When i am new jars it is not working .

Comment: What is `objectID`? Use proper case for field/getter/setter names.

Comment: Which version of Struts?

Comment: struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar and struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.15.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters should ideally be in your ActionForm(form bean) class rather than your Action class

```
public class LoginForm extends ActionForm {

private String nOrder;

public void setNOrder(String norder){
this.Norder=norder;}
public String getNOrder(){
return Norder;
}
}
```

Use struts tags for your jsps:

```
<html:text property="nOrder" />
```

Are you trying to pre-populate your form with any values are when do you want your jsp to show some values in the text box?

Comment: Thanku for ur replay :)

Comment: It was working fine and as u mentioned getter and setter methods are in action form only .When i upgraded some struts jar then it is not working .

Comment: It will work fine when i changed setter and getter method as show below

Comment: It will work fine when i changed setter and getter method as show below public void setnOrder(String norder){
      this.Norder=norder;}
public String getnOrder(){
     return Norder;
} and it wont work for following setter and getter methods public void setNOrder(String norder){
this.Norder=norder;}
public String getNOrder(){
return Norder;
}